# pytest says fixture not found when I'm not using one

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm trying to paramaterize test scenarios so I don't have to make seperate cases for each scenario like in xUnit style testing.

Here is an example from pytest that I'm trying to replicate for my own usecase.

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

testdata = [
    (datetime(2001, 12, 12), datetime(2001, 12, 11), timedelta(1)),
    (datetime(2001, 12, 11), datetime(2001, 12, 12), timedelta(-1)),
]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,b,expected", testdata)
def test_timedistance_v0(a, b, expected):
    diff = a - b
    assert diff == expected
```

The above works just fine, But when I try to modify it for my use like seen below. I get an error that says "dump" fixture not found. I don't get what's happening. This is my first time using pytest so maybe I'm not getting something.

```
dump1 = load_dump(pathtodump1,pathtodump2) # load_dump can take multiple params
dump2 = load_dump(pathtodump3)

scenarios = [(dump1,{'prod_str':None}),
             (dump2,{'prod_str':"123"})]

@pytest.mark.paramaterize("dump,expected_meta", scenarios)
def test_metadump_profiles(dump, expected_meta):
        meta = dump.meta
        assert meta.prod_str == expected_meta['prod_str']
```

This is the Error I get from pytest. I should also mention that when I debugged the test never runs, it fails somewhere in the paramaterize decorator.

```
========================================================================= ERRORS ==========================================================================
________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_metadump_profiles _________________________________________________________
file /x/x/x-x/x/x/x/x/x/x/test_x.py, line 81
  @pytest.mark.paramaterize("dump,expect_meta", scenarios)
  def test_metadump_profiles(dump, expect_meta):
        fixture 'dump' not found
        available fixtures: capfd, capsys, recwarn, tmpdir_factory, tmpdir, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, cache
        use 'py.test --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.


.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@pytest.mark.paramaterize
```

this is invalid and pytest throws an ambiguous error that makes no sense. This is caused by a spelling error...

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize
```

is the valid spelling. Stupidest bug I've pulled my hair out on.
see [github issue on this topic for more info.](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/695)